# Replace string if it has a common pattern

Tags: text-processing

I have a file like the following:

```
0/1:34:89:09    0/0:985:083:67 0/1:687:90887:975    0/1:54:79:25    0/0:5:83:67 0/1:67:9087:97  0/1:574:779:225 0/0:275:73:627 0/1:67:47:77
```

I want to replace any column which have `0/0` in the beginning with `homo`, so that my desired file will look like the following:

```
0/1:34:89:09    homo 0/1:687:90887:975  0/1:54:79:25    homo 0/1:67:9087:97 0/1:574:779:225 homo 0/1:67:47:77
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume "homo" refers to "same", as in this processing will be applied equally across all input files, regardless of extension.

`sed -iBAK 's_\(0/0:[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+\)_homo_g' text.txt`

The `-iBAK` makes a backup of the original file with a BAK suffix.

Comment: @user163263 If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: sorry I didn't know that . anyway the file I am working with is a vcf file . this command is working fine with a simple text file but not with the vcf file .

Comment: Vcf, as in VCard File? I don't recall if that's a binary file type. If sed sees it as a binary type it may not work. Also, I escaped a bunch of stuff in my answer. If you have that in a script it might not be necessary, or you might have to escape other chars.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed -r 's|0/0[^ $]+|homo|g'`:

```
$ echo "0/1:34:89:09 0/0:985:083:67 0/1:687:90887:975 0/1:54:79:25 0/0:5:83:67 0/1:67:9087:97 0/1:574:779:225 0/0:275:73:627 0/1:67:47:77 0/0:275:73:628" | \
sed -r 's|0/0[^ $]+|homo|g'
0/1:34:89:09 homo 0/1:687:90887:975 0/1:54:79:25 homo 0/1:67:9087:97 0/1:574:779:225 homo 0/1:67:47:77 homo
```